# Convergence/Divergence of an infinite series

Tags: limits

The problem in question is as follows

Determine convergence or divergence using any method covered so far:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{4^{-n} + 5^{-n}}$$

I started by using the limit comparison test with the above sequence being the $\frac{n}{4^{-n} + 5^{-n}}$ and the sequence in the denominator being $\frac{1}{n}$.

The sequence ended up going to infinity implying that both series converge. Is this correct?

I am kind of confused. Could the sequence I arbitrarily selected to be in the denominator have been ANY sequence that was positive and gave a limit if used as the denominator of the first sequence?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{n}{4^{-n}+5^{-n}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{n4^n}{1+\frac{4^n}{5^n}}$$
and $$1+\frac{4^n}{5^n}<n \quad{\text{If  n>1}}$$

Comment: Thanks for this, also can you tell me where I went wrong with my first attempt at solving the problem?

Comment: the series $\frac{1}{n}$ diverges

Comment: Doesn't the limit comparison test state that if the limit of sequence as n goes to infinity A/B goes to infinity, then the infinite series for sequence A and B converge?

Comment: @AbdallahHammam, yes, so the series diverges

Comment: @E.H.E Yes friend, it goes to $\infty$ .

Comment: So the limit of the sequence (n)/(4^-n + 5^-n) divided by (1/n) can be simplified to (n^2)/(4^-n + 5^-n) which diverges to infinity.  Then, by the limit comparison test, that means that both the infinite series 1/n and (n)/(4^-n + 5^-n) converge?

Comment: Are you saying that it is a requirement that the term chosen to compare with the original function doesn't diverge on its own? It doesn't say that in my book...

Comment: @Andrew I couldn't understand what do you mean.